# control size of alert dialog box in android

Tags: android

I have some code for displaying an alert dialog from one of my activities in Android.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Message");
    builder.setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        }
                    });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.setTitle("Title");
    alert.setIcon(R.drawable.your_image);      
    alert.show();
```

Now I would like to change the size of the dialog.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the link u can handle dialog size

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html

Comment: What method are you talking about?