# Custom Alert Dialog

Tags: java, android, alert

**custom alert dialog box**

How to set the size of xml layout (as dailog box) in custom alert dialog box using Dialog Class?
i want to increas the size of dialog xml layout ?how can i set the size of alert box?

**CODE**

```
`Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.extra);
        Button btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        dialog.setTitle("Just Dial");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.show();
```

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't do this!  The AlertDialog is sized appropriately by the system for all different screen sizes, so changing it is only going to make it not work correctly on these devices.

Answer (score 0):

You problem had already covered here: [control size of alert dialog box in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232177/control-size-of-alert-dialog-box-in-android#answer-4665934). Give a shot for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You try This Xml in R.layout.extra

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="250dp"
    android:minHeight="550dp">

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written

Comment: Thanks, He need . "set the size of xml layout ". so i did provide the Code